# MS Access, get quartiles(percentage)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, percentage, quartile

I need to call this function in a query that sorts the records (Values) by year and cohort. E.g.: where Year 1 is Year 1 and Cohort A is Cohort A, give me Min, Max, Median and Quartiles for the Values from Cohort A.
Can you please show how I would apply this function in a query design? Thank you

```
Public Function GetQuartile( _
  ByVal strTable As String, _
  ByVal strField As String, _
  ByVal bytQuartile As Byte, _
  Optional ByVal bytMethod As Byte, _
  Optional ByVal strFilter As String) _
  As Double

  ' strTable :    Name of the table/query to analyze.
  ' strField :    Name of the field to analyze.
  ' bytQuartile:  Which min/max or median/quartile to calculate.
  ' bytMethod:    Method for calculation of lower/higher quartile.
  ' strFilter:    Optional filter expression.
  '
  ' Returns:
  '   Minimum, maximum, median or upper/lower quartile
  '   of strField of strTable filtered on strFilter.
  '
  ' 2006-03-05. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.


' Reference for methods for calculation as explained here:
'   http://www.daheiser.info/excel/notes/noteh.pdf
' Note: Table H-4, p. 4, has correct data for dataset 1-96 while
'   datasets 1-100 to 1-97 actually are datasets 1-99 to 1-96
'   shifted one column left.
'   Thus, the dataset 1-100 is missing.
'
'   Method 3b is not implemented as no one seems to use it.
'   Neither are no example data given.
'
' Further notes on methods here:
'   http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/60969.html
'   http://www.haiweb.org/medicineprices/manual/quartiles_iTSS.pdf
'
' Data must be in ascending order by strField.


' L: Q1, Lower quartile.
' H: Q3, Higher quartile.
' M: Q2, Median.
' n: Count of elements.
' p: Calculated position of quartile.
' j: Element of dataset.
' g: Decimal part of p
'    to be used for interpolation between j and j+1.

' Basic operation.
' Constant values mimic those of Excel's Quartile() function.

' Find median.
Const cbytQuartMedian             As Byte = 2
' Find lower (first) quartile.
Const cbytQuartLow                As Byte = 1
' Find upper (third) quartile.
Const cbytQuartHigh               As Byte = 3
' Find minimum value.
Const cbytQuartMinimum            As Byte = 0
' Find maximum value.
Const cbytQuartMaximum            As Byte = 4

' Define default operation.
Const cbytQuartDefault = cbytQuartMedian

' Quartile calculation methods.

' Step. Mendenhall and Sincich method.
' SAS #3.
' Round up to actual element of dataset.
' L: -Int(-n/4)
' H: n-Int(-n/4)
Const cbytMethodMendenhallSincich As Byte = 1

' Average step.
' SAS #5, Minitab (%DESCRIBE), GLIM (percentile).
' Add bias of one or two on basis of n/4.
' L: (Int((n+1)/4)+Int(n/4))/2+1
' H: n-(Int((n+1)/4)+Int(n/4))/2+1
Const cbytMethodAverage           As Byte = 2

' Nearest integer to np.
' SAS #2.
' Round to nearest integer on basis of n/4.
' L: Int((n+2)/4)
' H: n-Int((n+2)/4)
' Note:
'   Reference contains an error in example data.
'   Dataset 1-100 to 1-97 (is really 1-99 to 1-96!) should read:
'   25  25  24  24
Const cbytMethodNearestInteger    As Byte = 3

' Parzen method.
' Method 1 with interpolation.
' SAS #1.
' L: n/4
' H: 3n/4
Const cbytMethodParzen            As Byte = 4

' Hazen method.
' Values midway between method 1 steps.
' GLIM (interpolate).
' Add bias of 2, don't round to actual element of dataset.
' L: (n+2)/4
' H: 3(n+2)/4
Const cbytMethodHazen             As Byte = 5

' Weibull method.
' SAS #4. Minitab (DECRIBE), SPSS, BMDP.
' Add bias of 1, don't round to actual element of dataset.
' L: (n+1)/4
' H: 3(n+1)/4
Const cbytMethodWeibull           As Byte = 6

' Freund, J. and Perles, B., Gumbell method.
' S-PLUS, R, Excel, Star Office Calc.
' Add bias of 3, don't round to actual element of dataset.
' L: (n+3)/4
' H: (3n+1)/4
Const cbytMethodFreundPerles      As Byte = 7

' Median Position.
' Median unbiased.
' L: (3n+5)/12
' H: (9n+7)/12
Const cbytMethodMedianPosition    As Byte = 8

' Bernard and Bos-Levenbach.
' L: (n/4)+0.4
' H: (3n/4)/+0.6
' Note:
'   Reference claims L to be (n/4)+0.31.
Const cbytMethodBernardLevenbach  As Byte = 9

' Blom's Plotting Position.
' Better approximation when the distribution is normal.
' L: (4n+7)/16
' H: (12n+9)/16
Const cbytMethodBlom              As Byte = 10

' Moore's first method.
' Add bias of one half step.
' L: (n+0.5)/4
' H: n-(n+0.5)/4
Const cbytMethodMoore1            As Byte = 11

' Moore's second method.
' Add bias of one or two steps on basis of (n+1)/4.
' L: (Int((n+1)/4)+Int(n/4))/2+1
' H: n-(Int((n+1)/4)+Int(n/4))/2+1
Const cbytMethodMoore2            As Byte = 12

' John Tukey's method.
' Include median from odd dataset in dataset for quartile.
' L: (1-Int(-n/2))/2
' H: n-(1-Int(-n/2))/2
Const cbytMethodTukey             As Byte = 13

' Moore and McCabe (M & M), variation of John Tukey's method.
' TI-83.
' Exclude median from odd dataset in dataset for quartile.
' L: (Int(n/2)+1)/2
' H: n-(Int(n/2)+1)/2
Const cbytMethodTukeyMM           As Byte = 14

' Additional variations between Weibull's and Hazen's methods, from
'   (i-0.000)/(n+1.00)
' to
'   (i-0.500)/(n+0.00)
'
' Variation of Weibull.
' L: n(n/4-0)/(n+1)
' H: n(3n/4-0)/(n+1)
Const cbytMethodModWeibull        As Byte = 15
' Variation of Blom.
' L: n(n/4-3/8)/(n+1/4)
' H: n(3n/4-3/8)/(n+1/4)
Const cbytMethodModBlom           As Byte = 16
' Variation of Tukey.
' L: n(n/4-1/3)/(n+1/3)
' H: n(3n/4-1/3)/(n+1/3)
Const cbytMethodModTukey          As Byte = 17
' Variation of Cunnane.
' L: n(n/4-2/5)/(n+1/5)
' H: n(3n/4-2/5)/(n+1/5)
Const cbytMethodModCunnane        As Byte = 18
' Variation of Gringorten.
' L: n(n/4-0.44)/(n+0.12)
' H: n(3n/4-0.44)/(n+0.12)
Const cbytMethodModGringorten     As Byte = 19
' Variation of Hazen.
' L: n(n/4-1/2)/n
' H: n(3n/4-1/2)/n
Const cbytMethodModHazen          As Byte = 20


' Define default method to calculate quartiles.
Const cbytMethodDefault = cbytMethodFreundPerles

Static dbs      As DAO.Database
Static rst      As DAO.Recordset

Dim strSQL      As String
Dim lngNumber   As Long
Dim dblPosition As Double
Dim lngPosition As Long
Dim dblInterpol As Double
Dim dblValueOne As Double
Dim dblValueTwo As Double
Dim dblQuartile As Double

' Use default calculation if choice of calculation is outside range.
If bytQuartile > 4 Then
  bytQuartile = cbytQuartDefault
End If
' Use default method if choice of method is outside range.
If bytMethod = 0 Or bytMethod > 20 Then
  bytMethod = cbytMethodDefault
End If

If dbs Is Nothing Then
  Set dbs = CurrentDb()
End If

If Len(strTable) > 0 And Len(strField) > 0 Then
  strSQL = "SELECT [" & strField & "] FROM [" & strTable & "] "
  strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE ([" & strField & "] Is Not Null) "
  If Len(strFilter) > 0 Then
    strSQL = strSQL & "AND (" & strFilter & ") "
  End If
  strSQL = strSQL & "ORDER BY [" & strField & "];"

  Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

  With rst
    If Not .EOF = True Then
      If bytQuartile = cbytQuartMinimum Then
        ' No need to count records.
        lngNumber = 1
      Else
        ' Count records.
        .MoveLast
        lngNumber = .RecordCount
      End If
      Select Case bytQuartile
        Case cbytQuartMinimum
          ' Current record is first record.
          ' Read value of this record.
        Case cbytQuartMaximum
          ' Current record is last record.
          ' Read value of this record.
        Case cbytQuartMedian
          ' Locate position of median.
          dblPosition = (lngNumber + 1) / 2
        Case cbytQuartLow
          Select Case bytMethod
            Case cbytMethodMendenhallSincich
              dblPosition = -Int(-lngNumber / 4)
            Case cbytMethodAverage
              dblPosition = (Int((lngNumber + 1) / 4) + Int(lngNumber / 4)) / 2 + 1
            Case cbytMethodNearestInteger
              dblPosition = Int((lngNumber + 2) / 4)
            Case cbytMethodParzen
              dblPosition = lngNumber / 4
            Case cbytMethodHazen
              dblPosition = (lngNumber + 2) / 4
            Case cbytMethodWeibull
              dblPosition = (lngNumber + 1) / 4
            Case cbytMethodFreundPerles
              dblPosition = (lngNumber + 3) / 4
            Case cbytMethodMedianPosition
              dblPosition = (3 * lngNumber + 5) / 12
            Case cbytMethodBernardLevenbach
              dblPosition = (lngNumber / 4) + 0.4
            Case cbytMethodBlom
              dblPosition = (4 * lngNumber + 7) / 16
            Case cbytMethodMoore1
              dblPosition = (lngNumber + 0.5) / 4
            Case cbytMethodMoore2
              dblPosition = (Int((lngNumber + 1) / 4) + Int(lngNumber / 4)) / 2 + 1
            Case cbytMethodTukey
              dblPosition = (1 - Int(-lngNumber / 2)) / 2
            Case cbytMethodTukeyMM
              dblPosition = (Int(lngNumber / 2) + 1) / 2
            Case cbytMethodModWeibull
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (lngNumber / 4) / (lngNumber + 1)
            Case cbytMethodModBlom
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (lngNumber / 4 - 3 / 8) / (lngNumber + 1 / 4)
            Case cbytMethodModTukey
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (lngNumber / 4 - 1 / 3) / (lngNumber + 1 / 3)
            Case cbytMethodModCunnane
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (lngNumber / 4 - 2 / 5) / (lngNumber + 1 / 5)
            Case cbytMethodModGringorten
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (lngNumber / 4 - 0.44) / (lngNumber + 0.12)
            Case cbytMethodModHazen
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (lngNumber / 4 - 1 / 2) / lngNumber
          End Select
        Case cbytQuartHigh
          Select Case bytMethod
            Case cbytMethodMendenhallSincich
              dblPosition = lngNumber - (-Int(-lngNumber / 4))
            Case cbytMethodAverage
              dblPosition = lngNumber - (Int((lngNumber + 1) / 4) + Int(lngNumber / 4)) / 2 + 1
            Case cbytMethodNearestInteger
              dblPosition = lngNumber - Int((lngNumber + 2) / 4)
            Case cbytMethodParzen
              dblPosition = 3 * lngNumber / 4
            Case cbytMethodHazen
              dblPosition = 3 * (lngNumber + 2) / 4
            Case cbytMethodWeibull
              dblPosition = 3 * (lngNumber + 1) / 4
            Case cbytMethodFreundPerles
              dblPosition = (3 * lngNumber + 1) / 4
            Case cbytMethodMedianPosition
              dblPosition = (9 * lngNumber + 7) / 12
            Case cbytMethodBernardLevenbach
              dblPosition = (3 * lngNumber / 4) + 0.6
            Case cbytMethodBlom
              dblPosition = (12 * lngNumber + 9) / 16
            Case cbytMethodMoore1
              dblPosition = lngNumber - (lngNumber + 0.5) / 4
            Case cbytMethodMoore2
              dblPosition = lngNumber - (Int((lngNumber + 1) / 4) + Int(lngNumber / 4)) / 2 + 1
            Case cbytMethodTukey
              dblPosition = lngNumber - (1 - Int(-lngNumber / 2)) / 2
            Case cbytMethodTukeyMM
              dblPosition = lngNumber - (Int(lngNumber / 2) + 1) / 2
            Case cbytMethodModWeibull
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (3 * lngNumber / 4) / (lngNumber + 1)
            Case cbytMethodModBlom
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (3 * lngNumber / 4 - 3 / 8) / (lngNumber + 1 / 4)
            Case cbytMethodModTukey
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (3 * lngNumber / 4 - 1 / 3) / (lngNumber + 1 / 3)
            Case cbytMethodModCunnane
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (3 * lngNumber / 4 - 2 / 5) / (lngNumber + 1 / 5)
            Case cbytMethodModGringorten
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (3 * lngNumber / 4 - 0.44) / (lngNumber + 0.12)
            Case cbytMethodModHazen
              dblPosition = lngNumber * (3 * lngNumber / 4 - 1 / 2) / lngNumber
          End Select
      End Select
      Select Case bytQuartile
        Case cbytQuartMinimum, cbytQuartMaximum
          ' Read current row.
        Case Else
          .MoveFirst
          ' Find position of first observation to retrieve.
          ' If lngPosition is 0, then upper position is first record.
          ' If lngPosition is not 0 and position is not an integer, then
          ' read the next observation too.
          lngPosition = Fix(dblPosition)
          dblInterpol = dblPosition - lngPosition
          If lngNumber = 1 Then
            ' Nowhere else to move.
            If dblInterpol < 0 Then
              ' Prevent values to be created by extrapolation beyond zero from observation one
              ' for these methods:
              '   cbytMethodModBlom
              '   cbytMethodModTukey
              '   cbytMethodModCunnane
              '   cbytMethodModGringorten
              '   cbytMethodModHazen
              '
              ' Comment this line out, if reading by extrapolation *is* requested.
              dblInterpol = 0
            End If
          ElseIf lngPosition > 1 Then
            ' Move to record to read.
            .Move lngPosition - 1
          End If
      End Select
      ' Retrieve value from first observation.
      dblValueOne = .Fields(0).Value

      Select Case bytQuartile
        Case cbytQuartMinimum, cbytQuartMaximum
          dblQuartile = dblValueOne
        Case Else
          If dblInterpol = 0 Then
            ' Only one observation to read.
            If lngPosition = 0 Then
              ' Return 0.
            Else
              dblQuartile = dblValueOne
            End If
          Else
            If lngPosition = 0 Then
              ' No first observation to retrieve.
              dblValueTwo = dblValueOne
              If dblValueOne > 0 Then
                ' Use 0 as other observation.
                dblValueOne = 0
              Else
                dblValueOne = 2 * dblValueOne
              End If
            Else
              ' Move to next observation.
              .MoveNext
              ' Retrieve value from second observation.
              dblValueTwo = .Fields(0).Value
            End If
            ' For positive values interpolate between 0 and dblValueOne.
            ' For negative values interpolate between 2 * dblValueOne and dblValueOne.
            ' Calculate quartile using linear interpolation.
            dblQuartile = dblValueOne + dblInterpol * CDec(dblValueTwo - dblValueOne)
          End If
      End Select
    End If
    .Close
  End With
Else
  ' Reset.
  Set rst = Nothing
  Set dbs = Nothing
End If

''Set rst = Nothing

  GetQuartile = dblQuartile

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide any sample data or expected results but - as the function can return one value only - you will most likely have to use the function in a subquery which you join to the main query on the field you group by in the main query. This way you will filter on the value you group by in the main query.

This will give you the requested Quartile(s). Min, Max, and Median can be obtained with the native function of Access.

**Edit**

Actually, it could be something like this:

```
SELECT 
    GroupByField, 
    GetQuartile("YourTable","ValueField",1,"GroupByField='" & [GroupByField] & "'") AS Q1, 
    GetQuartile("YourTable","ValueField",2,"GroupByField='" & [GroupByField] & "'") AS Q2, 
    GetQuartile("YourTable","ValueField",3,"GroupByField='" & [GroupByField] & "'") AS Q3, 
      (Select Avg(ValueField) 
      From YourTable As T 
      Where T.GroupByField = YourTable.GroupByField;) AS 
    AvgValue
  FROM 
    YourTable
  GROUP BY 
    GroupByField;
```

Comment: Thank you Gustav, but can you tell me the way that how can I apply the code above to return the quartiles? Its a bit hard for me to understand what you are saying.. sorry about that

Comment: it says "undefined function 'GetQuartile' in expression'

Comment: You will have to copy-n-paste the function above into a (new) module, then compile and save the module.