# How do i divide group/data by % in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is the current code i have, it divides users by their "FWB" Score into distinct categories, just coping, doing great, getting by etc..

```
SELECT FWBScore, gender,respondentname,
IIf(FWBScore<=22.5,"Having Trouble",IIf(FWBScore>=25 AND FWBScore<=47.5,"Just Coping",IIf(FWBScore>=50. AND FWBScore<=75.0,"Getting By",IIf(FWBScore>=77.5,"Doing Great","Doing Great")))) AS Categories
FROM RESPONDENT;
```

Now instead of dividing them by their FWB score, i want to divide them by the % of people who responded in each category for example, the end result would look something like this

```
Doing Great  Getting by   Just Coping
24%           15%            10%
```

Any Help with this would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Exactly what is the formula you use to arrive at those percentages? Edit question to show sample raw data as text table.

Comment: Your output shows an aggregate percentage - does not 'divide users into categories'. So you don't want to see individuals in the output? If you want to assign records to percentile groups, review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41643391/ms-access-get-quartilespercentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest just using a subquery and aggregating.  I suspect you want:

```
SELECT AVG(IIF(Category = "Having Trouble", 100.0, 0)) as having_trouble,
       AVG(IIF(Category = "Just Coping", 100.0, 0)) as just_coping,
       AVG(IIF(Category = "Getting By", 100.0, 0)) as getting_by,
       AVG(IIF(Category = "Doing Great", 100.0, 0)) as doing_great      
FROM (SELECT FWBScore, gender, respondentname,
             IIf(FWBScore <= 22.5, "Having Trouble",
                 IIf(FWBScore >= 25 AND FWBScore <= 47.5, "Just Coping",
                     IIf(FWBScore >= 50. AND FWBScore <= 75.0, "Getting By",
                         IIf(FWBScore >= 77.5, "Doing Great", "Doing Great")
                        )
                    )
                ) AS Category
      FROM RESPONDENT
     ) as r;
```

First note.  You can simplify all those `iif()` conditions by using `switch()`.

Second note.  Strictly speaking, the subquery is not necessary.  You can move the conditions to the outer query.  I used the subquery so I could leave your original logic.

EDIT:

Using `switch()`:

```
FROM (SELECT FWBScore, gender, respondentname,
             SWITCH(FWBScore <= 22.5, "Having Trouble",
                    FWBScore >= 25 AND FWBScore <= 47.5, "Just Coping",
                    FWBScore >= 50. AND FWBScore <= 75.0, "Getting By",
                    FWBScore >= 77.5, "Doing Great", "Doing Great"
                   ) AS Category
      FROM RESPONDENT
     ) as r;
```

Comment: P.s how would the switch function differ from he iff() function ?